# Automated testing framework for WSO2 applications

Tags: wso2

We're developing an app using WSO2 Data Analytics server and are in the process of developing integration tests for the REST apis. The endpoints are built using Spring and Spring Boot 1.3.3. We're using Data Analytics Server 3.0.1 with Postgres 9.5

Is WSO2 Automated Test Framework compatible with current versions of Data Analytics Server?

Answer (score 0):

To write integration tests for DAS related features, you can use the integration-test utils available at https://github.com/wso2/product-das/tree/master/modules/integration/tests-common.